Different degrees of diachronic stability for different phonological properties?
Has any research sought to identify which types of phonemes or phonological features tend to be more or less resistant to change over time relative to others? I'd love to know of any relevant research on the matter. From my own limited experience in comparative Afroasiatic, certainly some groups of consonants are more common culprits for change than others, especially glides and laryngeal consonants.
I'd also like to know if any research has addressed whether the structure of words biases degrees of change. Ex., are word-initial consonants more resistant to change than word-final consonants? Onsets vs. codas? Are stressed syllables more or less conservative than unstressed ones? Are closed syllables more stable than open ones? And so on.

It seems linguists are not interested in this topic. I read some literatures claiming that: 1) there is no such stable phoneme but the stability always depends on the environment. 2)"n" is relatively stable in IE langs (but not other families) and it is not in the lenition chain 3) (In many SEA/EA langs) Coda: voiced stops devoiced and lenition, h/s/r/l disappeared then p/t/k and then n/ng/m are the last to stay hence relatively "strong" 4) Vowels are harder to define and more volatile than consonants in general 5) Stress can shift and I wonder if it is more unstable than some consonants
